# Azure resource provider stuck in registering

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Azure seems to be stuck in Registering. Have been at this for hours. What is the magic touch to fix this?

```
thomas@Azure:~$ az account set -s XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
thomas@Azure:~$ az provider show --namespace microsoft.insights -o table

Namespace           RegistrationPolicy    RegistrationState
------------------  --------------------  -------------------
microsoft.insights  RegistrationRequired  Registering
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this issue is not still affecting you, but we do hear about this from a few customers and that the state changes to **Registered** eventually after a few hours. If the issue persists, please create an issue with the Azure CLI team [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues) so they can take a look.

There could have been a service issue at the time that could have impacted common management operations. You can check the [Azure Status page](https://status.azure.com/status/) to view all services that report their service health, as well as incidents with wide-ranging impact.

There's also the [Service Health dashboard](https://aka.ms/azureservicehealth) where you can track active events like ongoing service issues, upcoming planned maintenance, or relevant health advisories. While **Azure Service Health** tracks health events that may impact your resources, **Azure Resource Health** shows all the times that your resources have been unavailable because of Azure service problems.

Some other alternatives that you can try to register a resource provider are through the [Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-portal), and via [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-powershell).

To register a resource provider, use:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Insights
```

To see information for a particular resource provider, use:

```
Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Insights
```